# Authenticating Drupal Users Using Remote Call to Active Directory Single-Sign-On, How do I do it?

Tags: drupal, active-directory, single-sign-on

**QUESTION:** Authenticating Drupal Users Using Remote Call to Active Directory Single-Sign-On(SSO), How do I do it?

**SPECS(DRUPAL_SYSTEM):** Linux-CentOS-5.X, Apache-2.X, PHP-5.X, Drupal-6.X

**CONTROL(DRUPAL_SYSTEM):** 100% control of Drupal server making call to Authenticating server using Active Directory Single-Sign-On

**SPECS(SSO_SYSTEM):** Currently Unknown, but run by same company

**CONTROL(SSO_SYSTEM):** None Currently, but run by same company

**LEVEL_OF_KNOWLEDGE:** Basic for all systems listed, but able to trouble shoot tech subjects.

**Thanks in Advance!!**

TAGS: drupal single-sign-on active-directory authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules:

- Webserver
- Auth Webserver LDAP
- LDAP Provisioning
- LDAP Integration

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Have you done this before? I'm looking for an implementation based on the system specs I have. 

Also, are those four different approaches to solve the same problem, or a series of steps that is one answer? 

Is your refernce to "Webserver" and "Auth Webserver LDAP" mean to do "Single Sign-On with Apache and Active Directory" or something else?

Comment: Also, I believe by "LDAP Integration" your talking about:
http://drupal.org/project/ldap_integration
DOCs: http://drupal.org/node/62217

Do you have a link to "LDAP Integration" a how to?

And by "LDAP Provisioning"  I believe your talking about:
http://drupal.org/project/ldap_provisioning
DOCs: (none found, link please)

Do you have a link to "LDAP Provisioning" DOCs or a how to?